# Eclipse/GCC: Undefined Reference to Extern Variable

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, linker, global-variables

sorry if this is a repeated question, but I've been searching around for a couple of hours, and I'm getting conflicting answers... and what's worse, none of them are working.

It's a simple matter. I have many source files, and I have some common parameters that I want to be in a single file, say "Parameters.h". I want to set these parameters (once) at runtime, by passing them as arguments to the program.

PS: I know that a better way of doing it is to pass everything as arguments to functions, but it's a chunky piece of code and I need to get a result soon without making too many changes.

Here is a minimal working example:

**Parameters.h**

```
#ifndef PARAMETERS_H_
#define PARAMETERS_H_

extern int Alpha;

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Parameters.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    const int Alpha = 12.0;
}
```

**Functions.cpp**

```
#include "Parameters.h"

double Foo(const double& x)
{
    return Alpha*x;
}
```

When I compile with

```
gcc main.cpp Functions.cpp
```

I get the error "Functions.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `Alpha'".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have declared a global variable named `Alpha`, but you haven't defined it. In exactly one source file, write at file scope:

```
int Alpha;
```

or with an initializer:

```
int Alpha = 42;
```

Note that the local variable named `Alpha` you have defined within `main` is distinct from and completely unrelated to this global variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was, as you say, that I wasn't defining Alpha in the file scope in main.cpp. Now I feel like an idiot :-) Thanks again.

Comment: is there any need to define Alpha as `extern` considering the declaration is in a header file?

Comment: @ldgorman: If you don't use `extern`, then it would be a definition, not merely a declaration. If you then include this header into more than one source file, you would get linker errors about multiple definitions of the same symbol.